# Trigger a function on receiving SMS via GSM modem

Tags: c#, gsm

I have developed a program to send and receive SMS via GSM modem using C# and AT commands. The only issue remains is that I want to fire the send SMS function as a reply as soon as the SMS is received on the GSM modem. I don't want to use loops or timers to trigger the function. The function should be triggered as soon as the SMS is received. Any suggestions??

Comment: AT+CNMI= controls what notification message is sent to the DTE when a new message is received, thats what you would detect.

Comment: Yes but how do i use this command to trigger the send SMS function in visual C# ?

Comment: Configure it and the modem will send a string when a message is received, you would detect the message from the modem via the DataReceived event if your using a serial control.

Comment: That did the trick thanks :) @AlexK.